# Обе функции будут исполнены после выполнения основного потока?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, promise

```js
setTimeout(() => {}, 0)
// or
const func = async () => {}
func()
```

Comment: Нет. И это было бы гораздо быстрее проверить самостоятельно, чем ждать тут ответа. :)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-loop

Comment: @Yaant, да уже и проверил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую почитать про микро- и макро- таски и eventloop.

Сначала выполняется один макротаск (`setTimeout`), потом все микротаски (`async`, промисы и т.п), которые могут наплодить новые микротаски. Потом рендеринг/отрисовка. А потом всё это повторяется.

Comment: Этот ответ можно интепретировать так, будто функция `func()` выполнится после функции, вызванной через `setTimeout()`. Но это же не так!